# Eclipse: what's missing to generate JAXB XML bindings?

Tags: eclipse, jaxb

I am using Eclipse Oxygen with a Java 8 runtime.
I have an XML schema and I need to generate the corresponding XML -> Java bindings using JAXB. But when I right-click the .xsd File -> Generate -> JAXB classes..." and walk through the dialogs I get a warning "the classpath appears not to contain the necessary libraries to continue with class generation". And, indeed, when I proceed I end up in an exception "Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade".

Now, to my knowledge, Java since v1.6 contains all necessary JAXB libraries and tools. So, why is this not working?

As a variant I ticked the checkbox to use Eclipe's built-in "MOXy" implementation, but that doesn't work, either.

I then googled and found that I need to make sure that I have chosen a runtime that contains JAXB (i.e. one >= v1.6) but that's obviously the case here.

What do I need to add/download/configure to get this going? Any pointers or instructions welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Googling again (obviously this time with better search terms) I found [this post](http://mramanujam.blogspot.ch/2016/03/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class.html) which provided the solution: the chosen runtime in Eclipse has to be a JDK, not a JRE!

Apparently only the JDKs contain the required tools/libraries to get this JAXB translation  working. If only the error message would give a hint in that direction...

Adding the Java 8 JDK (which I had installed, too, besides the JRE) to the list of available runtimes in Eclipse and defining it as the default runtime did the trick.

Comment: The [`xjc` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html), which generated Java classes from an xsd, is indeed only included with the JDK and not with the JRE.